# One word to describe being 'committed to the environment'

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I say that I am committed to the environment in one word?

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence, so we can see how you will use the word?

Comment: I would suggest environment-friendly or "eco-friendly," but more context is needed to provide a specific answer.

Comment: A treehugger, perhaps?

Comment: @rhetorician, treehuggers are environmentalists but with negative connotations, too.

Comment: Point taken.  Don

Answer (score 9):

You are an **Environmentalist**

This term has had widespread use.

Answer (score 1):

Environmentalist, conservationalist, Naturalist

Answer (score 0):

You are [**green.**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green)(see definition 10)  That term is frequently used to describe lifestyles and practices by people and companies; e.g. GreenPeace, the well-known environmental group, and a Google search such as "green living" turns up lots of results.

Comment: @JackRyan http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green, definition 10a.  Also lots of use in print and video.

Comment: @JackRyan, also see GreenPeace, the well-known environmentalist group.

Comment: @JackRyan, Natural Geographic has a piece on "green living" at http://environment.nationalgeographic.com/environment/green-guide/.  "Green living" also gives lot of relevant results in Google.  This really is a common term, had you not heard of it before?